# How can I wrap the text of a long sentence within table sub-headings?

Tags: tables, wrap

I am struggling to make the subheadings of my table fit within the designated margins of the table. It all works and formats well when the sentences are not too long. Any suggestions are welcome. Please note that I cannot change the heading contents in any way.

Code:

```
%*** The Summary table **********************************************
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{|X|}
 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{Title of the project}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    Development of a Hybrid Brushless Exciter for the Field Supply of a Grid-Connected Wound-Rotor Wind Generator.\\
 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{Objectives}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    To conduct an analysis by means of basic analytical analysis and Ansys Maxwell finite element analysis. Additionally, to design the windings of a partly constructed brushless hybrid exciter, and to construct and test the design. Finally, to ensure that there is an improvement upon the current design.\\
 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{What is current practice and what are its limitations?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
   \\

 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{What is new in this project?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    \\
 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{If the project is successful, how will it make a difference?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
     \\

 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{What are the risks to the project being a success? Why is it expected to be successful?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    \\

 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{What contributions have/will other students made/make?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    %N/A.\\

 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{Which aspects of the project will carry on after completion and why?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    \\

 \hline%=============================================================
 \SumHead{What arrangements have been/will be made to expedite
    continuation?}\\
 \hline%=============================================================
    \\
 \hline%=============================================================

\end{tabularx}
```

[image: Preview of the Table]

It was brought to my attention that I forgot to include the \SumHead definition, here it is, attached:
[image: \SumHead Definition]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How is `\SumHead` defined currently?

Comment: Hi there, please see the original post - I edited it and included the \SumHead definition.

Comment: Thanks for editing your posting to provide your definition of the `\SumHead` macro. As I had suspected, it uses the `c` column type, which does *not* allow automatic line breaking. Compare this to the macro definition provided at the top of my answer, which employs a centered version of the `X` column type, which (by design) does allow line breaking.

Comment: @Mico thank you. After defining a similar function of the same nature (I could not edit the \SumHead macro), and replacing the "c" with "X", the problem was resolved. Thanks very much! I appreciate your assistance. Keep well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think that executing `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` in the preamble and (re)defining `\SumHead` as

```
\newcommand\SumHead[1]{\multicolumn{1}{%
   |>{\cellcolor{lightgray!33}\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries}X|}{#1}}
```

will let you achieve your formatting requirements, I'd like to suggest that you reconsider the entire design of the table. Specifically, do get rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, and arrive at something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \addlinespace macros
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\bfseries\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\providecommand\SumHead[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}Y@{}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{}X@{}}
 \toprule
 \SumHead{Title of the project}\\
 \addlinespace
 Development of a Hybrid Brushless Exciter for the Field Supply of a Grid-Connected Wound-Rotor Wind Generator.\\
 \midrule
 \SumHead{Objectives}\\
 To conduct an analysis by means of basic analytical analysis and Ansys Maxwell finite element analysis. Additionally, to design the windings of a partly constructed brushless hybrid exciter, and to construct and test the design. Finally, to ensure that there is an improvement upon the current design.\\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{What is current practice and what are its limitations?}\\
 \dots \\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{What is new in this project?}\\
 \dots  \\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{If the project is successful, how will it make a difference?}\\
 \dots \\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{What are the risks to the project being a success? Why is it expected to be successful?}\\
 \dots \\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{What contributions have\slash will other students made\slash make?}\\
 \dots \\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{Which aspects of the project will carry on after completion and why?}\\
 \dots \\
 \addlinespace
 \SumHead{What arrangements have been\slash will be made to expedite
    continuation?}\\
 \dots \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the reply! Unfortunately this did not work. I followed your suggestion of the new definition and of executing \usepackage. In response to the second part of your answer, I cannot change the formatting of the table. It is a faculty-wide standard and this is part of my thesis document. The suggestion is however, appreciated.

Comment: @Sebastian - Please see the slight tweak I applied to the definition of `\SumHead`. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Works now, thanks very much! Keep well.